# Trying to make name-based virtual hosts work on apache2 with self hosted DNS

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, apache2, webserver

I'm reading a book on Ubuntu Server and after wiring all the networking, DHCP, DNS, NTP and all, we got to the point where we need to create an apache2 web-server.

I followed all the instructions but when we got to the **multiple virtual host** part, I can't seem to make it work.

Having only one network interface, I opted for the **named-based virtual hosts**.
I'm going to list all my DHCP, DNS and Apache2 configurations to make it easy for everyone to figure the problem out.

**DHCP**

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
default-lease-time 43200;
max-lease-time 86400;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option domain-name "local.lan";
authoritative;
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.240;
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
}
```

**DNS**

/etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
options {
        forwarders {
          8.8.8.8;
          8.8.4.4;
        };
        dnssec-validation auto;
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
zone "local.lan" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/net.local.lan";
};
```

/etc/bind/net.local.lan

```
$TTL 1D
@ IN SOA local.lan. exampleemail.local.lan. (

202212152; serial

8H ; refresh
4H ; retry
4W ; expire
1D ) ; minimum
IN A 192.168.1.1
;
@ IN NS lenovo.local.lan.
lenovo     IN  A   192.168.1.1 #my server
```

**WEBSITE**

For the website configuration, I created a file called `000-virtual-hosts.conf` that holds the config for the virtual hosts I want to make work.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-virtual-hosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mywebsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myotherwebsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myotherwebsite_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myotherwebsite_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Call me a noob, but I don't know if the reason it doesn't work is because I don't own the `mywebsite.com` and `myotherwebsite.com` domains but I thought it would follow the example in the book and the domains would be requested specifically through port 80 and add the resolve to my server IP further in this post it would be local no matter if I own the domains or not.
I thought it could be the fact that they're pointing to the same `/var/www/html` file and that could be the problem.
I enabled them before I tried to make it work, `sudo a2ensite 000-virtual-hosts.conf` && `sudo systemctl reload apache2`.

The book at one point says: "*If you're using domain names with virtual hosts, then this will only work if you set up networking such that the domain name referenced in the file resolves to the IP address of your server. [...] If you're running your own DNS server, you would add the A record there.*"
So I added this line to `/etc/bind/net.local.lan` and updated the `serial` number, otherwise the DNS wouldn't accept the new host.

```
mywebsite.com IN A 192.168.1.247
```

But I think the problem is I really don't know what I'm doing/doing wrong.

Here are the logs caught by `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, I don't know if those logs could include connection failures to `mywebsite.com` because they're supposed to be for the default `.conf` file but I'm sharing them in case you need them.

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Dec 16 01:32:24.187718 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32022:tid 139897582640192] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to Apache on the local machine or on a different machine (or host) on the network?

Comment: I was trying to connect to Apache from another device that's on the same network. when I typed the IP:80 ( in this case `192.168.1.1:80`, `lenovo`'s IP referred to in the `/etc/bind/net.local.lan` file ) the default page works, but I tried typing `mywebsite.com:80` and it sent me to the actual .com instead. I can't really use the computer on which I've installed Apache since its screen doesn't really work so I connect to it using ssh.